# FFmpeg : reduce video size issue

Tags: android, video, ffmpeg, native

i don't have any knowledge with `FFmpeg` , i using below command in order to reduce video size via `FFmpeg` from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4490154/reducing-video-size-with-same-format-and-reducing-frame-size) , but outputted videos does not have video, they are only sound with black video.

```
ffmpeg -i in.mp4 -s 640x480 -b 512k -vcodec mpeg1video -acodec copy file.mp4
```

What is the issue?

Comment: invoke 'ffmpeg -i in.mp4'  , capture stdout and post that in order to give a clue as to 'tracks' and codecs used in the container

Comment: try these switch settings :  -vcodec libx264 -b:v 250k -f mp4 -strict -2

Comment: Thanks, can you please post full command?

Comment: It's really difficult to guess which kind of problem you have. Please, edit your post and add output from `ffmpeg -i in.mp4` command as Robert mentioned, or use `ffprobe` which is practically the same thing: `ffprobe in.mp4`.

Comment: Please show the complete console output from your command.