# Lossy compression for video files before being uploaded on server (Django web app)

Tags: python, django, video, ffmpeg

I need a bit of guidance. I have a Django app, where users upload photos and captions.

I want to integrate video uploading and playback as well. My question revolves specifically around video file size.

Most of my users have bandwidth issues. It's best if uploaded videos are *as small a size as possible* (quality can be compromised upon, it can be lossy). What's the best currently-supported Python library to get me started on this (an illustrative example)? I do something similar for photos uploaded on my site using Python Imaging Library.

---

[Pyffmpeg](http://mhaller.github.io/pyffmpeg/) seems to be the closest fit so far. But it doesn't seem to be supported any longer, nor do I find examples of what I'm trying to achieve. [ffmpeg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4490154/reducing-video-size-with-same-format-and-reducing-frame-size) seems to be well documented however.

Comment: I would just call ffmpeg directly through `subprocess.call` as it's a de facto standard for video compression, all those wrapper libraries are doing just proxying the calls to ffmpeg and adding extra limitations and learning curve.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm doing quite a similar task on my website using ffmpeg and subprocess. To get you started this might help -

```
subprocess.check_call(
            ['ffmpeg', '-v', '-8', '-i', input_video, '-vf', 'scale=-2:480', '-preset', 'slow',
             '-c:v', 'libx264', '-strict', 'experimental', '-c:a', 'aac', '-crf', '20', '-maxrate', '500k',
             '-bufsize', '500k', '-r', '25', '-f', 'mp4', output_video_mp4, '-y'])
```

This would call ffmpeg to convert 'input_video' (with full path) into file 'output_video_mp4' (with full path) having mp4 format at 480p.

Refer to this link for more information - 
https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-all.html

Comment: Pretty good start! Let me get back to you on this, and thanks :-)