# Muxing PCM audio into WMA increases file size significantly

Tags: ffmpeg

While I am trying to convert wav file to wma file size is becomes much larger than original source file:

- `input.wav` - 11M
- `output.wma` - 16M

Is there any way to reduce file size of output file?

Command and output:

```
$ ffmpeg -i input.wav -c copy output.wma

ffmpeg version N-80797-g8b4d6cc Copyright (c) 2000-2016 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 6.1.1 (GCC) 20160501
  configuration: --enable-gpl
  libavutil      55. 27.100 / 55. 27.100
  libavcodec     57. 48.101 / 57. 48.101
  libavformat    57. 40.101 / 57. 40.101
  libavdevice    57.  0.102 / 57.  0.102
  libavfilter     6. 46.102 /  6. 46.102
  libswscale      4.  1.100 /  4.  1.100
  libswresample   2.  1.100 /  2.  1.100
  libpostproc    54.  0.100 / 54.  0.100
Guessed Channel Layout for Input Stream #0.0 : stereo
Input #0, wav, from 'input.wav':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf57.40.101
  Duration: 00:01:00.00, bitrate: 1411 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Audio: pcm_s16le ([1][0][0][0] / 0x0001), 44100 Hz, 2 channels, s16, 1411 kb/s
Output #0, asf, to 'output.wma':
  Metadata:
    WM/EncodingSettings: Lavf57.40.101
    Stream #0:0: Audio: pcm_s16le ([1][0][0][0] / 0x0001), 44100 Hz, stereo, 1411 kb/s
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (copy)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
size=   16150kB time=00:01:00.00 bitrate=2205.1kbits/s speed=1.9e+03x    
video:0kB audio:10336kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 56.255745%
```

Comment: How do we duplicate the issue? Does the issue occur if you run the `ffmpeg` command manually, unscripted in a command line interface? Show the complete console output from the `ffmpeg` command.

Comment: @LordNeckbeard ,hope now u can debug my code..and ' ffmpeg.exe' is an executable solution for getting command line interface.

Comment: See this question : [Reducing video size with same format and reducing frame size](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4490154/reducing-video-size-with-same-format-and-reducing-frame-size)

Comment: You didn't answer my questions, so I can't help.

Comment: @LordNeckbeard ,,I am not run ffmpeg command manually,I have a .exe file for that

Comment: I asked you to run the command manually so we can determine if the issue is due to `ffmpeg` alone or due to your script.

Comment: @LordNeckbeard ,tried below code for the same                                  ffmpeg -i recording.wav -acodec copy newrecording.wma

Comment: @LordNeckbeard ffmpeg -i recording.wav -acodec copy newrecording.wma Run the above code and got same issues

Answer (score 3, accepted):

WMA is crappy. Try changing the packet size. From [FFmpeg ASF muxer documentation](https://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#asf-2):

> `-packet_size`
>   Set the muxer packet size. By tuning this setting you
>   may reduce data fragmentation or muxer overhead depending on your
>   source. Default value is 3200, minimum is 100, maximum is 64k.

Example:

```
ffmpeg -i input.wav -c copy -packet_size 65536 output_64k.wma
```

File sizes:

- `input.wav` - 11M
- `output_64k.wma` - 11M
- `output_default.wma` - 16M

Comment: Is there any downside to using a large `packet_size`?  Why isn't that the default?  (The use-case I care about is files played from disk or NFS, or other seekable media, not streaming.)  Does it increase the amount of demuxing / decoding required for a seek to a certain position in a WMV containing video + audio?

Comment: @PeterCordes For local(-ish) playback I don't think it matters, I am not aware of any downside, and I don't think it will mess up your seeking. I'm guessing the default is a balance weighted towards steaming usage. You may want to ask on ffmpeg-user: I don't use WMA/ASF, so maybe I'm wrong.