# Display time on video encode v4l2

Tags: c, linux, time, camera, v4l2

I am writing a C program on linux with the purpose of saving video from the camera to a file, using v4l2. I want the video to have the date and time it was recorded on. Is there any way to do that?

I try to read many api of v4l2 but they not work.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3169916/can-ffmpeg-burn-in-time-code